# Create double pointer on structure to use by index (like an array but max size unknown)

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to make items indexer with double pointer to be able get pointer to specific item by its number.

I would rather use array for this task, but max value of items is unknown.
So, I need somehow get access by index.

In VS i got error "Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000000"

```
typedef struct {
  char * data_3;
  int   data_1;
  float data_2;
  // and other data, doesnt matter
}obj_t;

void process_item(obj_t * input_item)
{
   // do something...
}

obj_t * create_new_item()
{
    obj_t * local_obj;
    // do something...
    return local_obj;
}

int get_max_items()
{
    return 8; // just some number, which can be set from outside
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    obj_t * item = NULL;
    obj_t ** item_indexer = NULL;

    for (i = 0; i < get_max_items(); i++)
    {
        item = create_new_item(); // create different items
        item_indexer[i] = &item;  // Error: access violation writing location 0x0000000000000000
    }

    process_item(item_indexer[i]); // need send item with specific index
}
```

I expected to use it like array:

```
item_indexer[0] is (*item) created at i = 0
item_indexer[1] is (*item) created at i = 1
...
```

and be able to send specific item

But I'm stuck with errors about access violations.

Comment: Where do you allocate the memory for `obj_t ** item_indexer` in main?  And where do you allocate the memory for `obj_t * local_obj` in create_new_item?  You need to allocate memory if you want to use it.

Comment: `item_indexer[i] = &item;`  You are dereferencing a NULL pointer,here.

Comment: Even if you did create memory for `obj_t ** item_indexer` in main you would have to say how much.  That's ok but then you can't just add unlimited items without checking to see if it is big enough or re-allocing in it isn't.

Comment: Hint: `location 0x0000000000000000` is a NULL pointer

Comment: @wildplasser yes indeed. Correct is ```item_indexer[i] = item;```

Comment: @JerryJeremiah allocation memory helped, thanks for guide!

Answer (score 0):

Need allocate memory for double pointer too:

```
item_indexer = calloc(get_max_items(), sizeof(obj_t));
```

And fix dereferencing pointer:

```
item_indexer[i] = item; // no need & here
```